# Callback without function pointer

Tags: c, callback

It is usually said callbacks are implemented with function pointers. When I check PortAudio's source code, I see that callback function is declared as an ordinary function (not a f. pointer). Is it normal/legal/advisable?

```
typedef int PaStreamCallback(
const void *input, void *output,
unsigned long frameCount,
const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
void *userData );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine as long as the parameter is used as `PaStreamCallback*` (which is a *pointer* to a *function*), like

```
PaError Pa_OpenStream   (
        PaStream **      stream,
        const PaStreamParameters *      inputParameters,
        const PaStreamParameters *      outputParameters,
        double      sampleRate,
        unsigned long   framesPerBuffer,
        PaStreamFlags   streamFlags,
        PaStreamCallback *      streamCallback,   // <---
        void *      userData     
    )
```

Comment: ok, thanks.
by the way, the functions are passed to Pa_OpenStream with their names only, however logically must be passed with addressof operator, but omitting & is a shortcut, right?

Comment: @paul if `foo` is a function, `foo` and `&foo` are equivalent.